# Signer issues with anchor tests

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, anchor-test, anchor-client, smart-contract

i'm getting a weird signer error when running my tests;

```
Error: Signature verification failed.
Missing signature for public key [`6jAudYFBbfQS59oPNjYcMkqr9MqBf312T7oP6WSYRjsg`].
```

In this case, `6jAudYFBbfQS59oPNjYcMkqr9MqBf312T7oP6WSYRjsg` is the state object's pubkey.

Here's the test code:

```
const state = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate()
await program.rpc.stake(
      stakePDABump,
      beefAccountBump,
      new anchor.BN(5_000),
      {
        accounts: {
          tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          stakeMint: stakeMintAddress,
          state: state.publicKey, // here
          stakeMintAuthority: stakePDA,
          programBeefTokenAccount: beefAccountPDA,
          userStakeTokenAccount: user.stakeTokenAccount,
          userBeefTokenAccount: user.beefTokenAccount,
          beefMint: beefMintAddress,
          userBeefTokenAccountAuthority: user.wallet,
        }
      },
    );
```

Here's the instruction:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateBeefTokenAccount<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        seeds = [ BEEF_MINT_ADDRESS.parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap().as_ref() ],
        bump,
        token::mint = beef_mint,
        token::authority = program_beef_token_account,
    )]
    pub program_beef_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        address = BEEF_MINT_ADDRESS.parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap(),
    )]
    pub beef_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = 8+State::MAXIMUM_SIZE)]
    pub state: Account<'info, State>,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your state should be a PDA so that your program can sign for it.

This would like smth like this:

```
#[account(  
        init,
        seeds = [b"state".as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8,
        payer = signer,
    )]
```

and in js you can then get the PDA like this:

```
const state = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("state")],
  program.programId
);
```

If you want to create the key yourself you need to sign for it
Which would look something like this:

```
const transaction = await program.methods
    .doSmth()
    .accounts({
      ...
    })
    .signers([state])
    .transaction();

  console.log("transaction", transaction);

  const txSig = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection,{
    signers: [state],
    skipPreflight: true
  } );
```